# How does "Find My Friends" (FMF) App respond to location?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, background-process, phonegap

I am trying to create an App that will respond with locations of people in a group when anyone requests it - similar to what Find My Friends (FMF) does but across Android and iOS and I am using Phonegap. I have been researching how the FMF App returns locations - along the lines of this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494135/find-my-friends-style-gps-remotely-ping-for-location) and am trying to understand that better.

At some point iOS will terminate the App due to memory pressure. I understand if you set your Background mode in Capabilities section of XCode to location and if there is a significant change in location the App will restart in Background. Is that what the FMF App is doing to ensure it stays up to respond to location request?

When location is requested I send a push notification (data notification only so it is processed in the background - users doesn't see it) and the App is expected to respond if it is in Background/Foreground. However in the case of iOS if the App has been terminated by iOS and there has been no significant location change, the App will not be up and running in Background and won't respond. Is that the best we can do besides somehow preventing iOS from suspending/terminating the App? Appreciate any insights.

I have read about creating background services to help but that seems to apply more to Android than to iOS.

Thank you for any guidance and pointers.

Sanjay.

Answer (score 0):

### First of all, you shoud [Declaring Your App’s Supported Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23).

Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by the app that uses them. In Xcode 5 and later, you declare the background modes your app supports from the Capabilities tab of your project settings. Enabling the Background Modes option adds the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Selecting one or more checkboxes adds the corresponding background mode values to that key.

### Then [Tracking the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW25) and cached the latest location.

### And handle your remote notification to upload the latest location.

When your want to get somebody's location, Server push a remote-notification to the Client with APNS, and Client handle the remote-notification with `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

Or timed to upload location with Finite-Length Tasks in the background:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

Hope that help you ~

Comment: Thanks @Grayland. When the server sends a data notification (with content-available set to 1) will that guarantee to restart the App if it has been terminated? Or do we have to rely on the Background location flag in Capabilities for iOS to restart the App when there is a significant location change? If latter then when the Application has been terminated by iOS and there has been no significant location change the App won't respond to data push notification - is that correct?

Comment: 1. will not; 2. Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur; 3.Correct, if the app was killed, it won't restart to respond anything. @SanjayTibrewal

Comment: Thanks @GrayLand - appreciate the answers. To further clarify (2), for iOS, once the application is terminated (by OS for memory or the User) and the Background Capabilities is set to location then does that guarantee that when there is a significant location change for the device iOS will restart the App in the background? Or does something else need to be in place for the App to be restarted in background?